# GCloud Deploying Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

When running `gcloud app deploy`, I receive the following:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...\Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py", line 83, in Ticker
    if self.Tick():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py", line 101, in Tick
    self._Print(_SPIN_MARKS[self._ticks % len(_SPIN_MARKS)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py", line 156, in _Print
    sys.stderr.write('\r' + console_width * ' ')
```

I am not exactly sure how the error orriginates. After the exception was thrown, the application still deployed, but I am not sure if the exception will later on effect my project in any way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you recall what exception was thrown?

Comment: it's in the code. It was just an issue with the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out the issue :) The code box above has the stack trace source lines. Typically that's followed by the exception name and message. For now I've ruled out an invalid value in console_width, based on how its initialized. That points to a problem with sys.stderr.write, and I'd like to confirm that. My guess is the main thread already started shutting down stdio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback it appears to be just some bug in displaying a progress bar.

I wouldn't worry about it.

If you want to be really, really certain just re-deploy.

Of course, it'd be much better to not have to see such errors, but I guess we're not there yet :)

Comment: Alright! Thanks man! I really appreciate it!  I have been tailing the logs and so far, my application has still been running.